# "U saw Jurassic Park movie in Hindi or English"

Tags: questions, do-support

Is this correct?

> U saw jurassic Park movie in Hindi or English

Comment: It's hard to say what it's correct when it's not clear what you want it to mean.

Answer (score 3):

First things first: why are you using "u"? Always write "you" in full!

I'm assuming that the dialogue you provided is meant to form a question. In this case, the best thing to say would be:

> Did you **see** the Jurassic Park movie in Hindi or English?

Notice that the verb "to see" is not conjugated because it somewhat acts as an object. *Did you see?* = *You did see* = subject, verb, object.

Comment: Are you sure that “see” can be considered an object here? I'd say that in certain constructions (questions, past tenses) the infinitive form of the verb “(to) see” is accompanied by an auxiliary verb, in this case “did”.